# There was an error communicating with the server. Please try again later. under Pronunciation

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I am getting this error message when I clicked the mic icon on the App information Pronunciation: There was an error communicating with the server. Please try again later.
And I also cannot save the information, getting the error message: Errors occurred when saving Assistant app information.

It is just happened today. I was able to do it yesterday. Any idea?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Refresh the page and try again, this is most likely caused by a lost session, no internet or a problem on Google's side.

Comment: I did it many times, logoff logon, same issue, different browser, computers, no luck at all

Comment: I just checked and I get the same error, so just wait it out I guess.

Comment: On what browser you are trying it? Are you on a good wifi connection?

Comment: Chrome browser with good wifi connection

Answer (score 0):

This error can be due to a number of reasons. In the screenshot there is an error communicating with the server which might mean too many requests are being made to the server and is unable to process your request at the moment. Or it might be because of a lost session, browser or adblock blocking a script, bad internet connection or maybe more RAM is needed.

You can try and refresh the page or make this request after some time.